# How to save decoded values in CoreData using Swift with proper values

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, codable

```
// Service.swift
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey.managedObjectContext] = self.coreDataManager.managedObjectContext
            do {
                _ = try decoder.decode([POI].self, from: jsonData)
                self.coreDataManager.saveContext()
                print("Saved")
            }
            catch{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
```

```
// POI+CoreDataClass.swift
@objc(POI)
public class POI: NSManagedObject, Codable {
    ...
    required public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        guard let context = decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey.managedObjectContext] as? NSManagedObjectContext else {
            throw DecoderConfigurationError.missingManagedObjectContext
            }
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "POI", in: context)!
        self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)

        let encodedValues = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        let idString = try encodedValues.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        self.id = UUID.init(uuidString: idString)!
        self.externalId = try encodedValues.decode(String.self, forKey: .externalId)
        self.title = try encodedValues.decode([String:String].self, forKey: .title)
        self.coordinates = try encodedValues.decode(Geometry.self, forKey: .coordinates)
        self.author = try encodedValues.decode(String.self, forKey: .author)
        self.imageUrl = try encodedValues.decode(String.self, forKey: .imageUrl)
        self.type = try encodedValues.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
        let propertyValues = try encodedValues.decode([String:Any].self, forKey: .properties)
        self.properties = propertyValues

    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(externalId, forKey: .externalId)
        try container.encode(title, forKey: .title)
        try container.encode(coordinates, forKey: .coordinates)
        try container.encode(author, forKey: .author)
        try container.encode(imageUrl, forKey: .imageUrl)
        try container.encode(type, forKey: .type)
        try container.encode(properties, forKey: .properties)
    }
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case externalId
        case title
        case coordinates
        case author
        case imageUrl
        case type
        case properties
    }
}

enum DecoderConfigurationError: Error {
  case missingManagedObjectContext
}

// POI+CoreDataProperties.swift
extension POI {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<POI> {
        return NSFetchRequest<POI>(entityName: "POI")
    }

    @NSManaged public var author: String
    @NSManaged public var coordinates: Geometry
    @NSManaged public var externalId: String
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var imageUrl: String
    @NSManaged public var properties: [String:Any]
    @NSManaged public var title: [String:String]
    @NSManaged public var type: String
}
```

```
// CoreDataManager.swift
...
func saveContext() {
      let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
      if context.hasChanges {
        do {
          try context.save()
        } catch {
          // The context couldn't be saved.
          let nserror = error as NSError
          fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
      }
    }
```

```
// Example.json
..
{
    "id": "0c0ef61d-9507-4400-8e5e-e7dc31a34370",
    "externalId": "node/1234567890",
    "title": {
      "de": "Küche",
      "en": "kitchen"
    },
    "coordinates": {
      "type": "Point",
      "values": [
        {
          "lat": 52.123456,
          "lon": 13.123456
        }
      ]
    },
    "author": "Authorname",
    "imageUrl": "null",
    "type": "Type",
    "properties": {
      "Website": {
        "de": "https://website.com/de"
      },
      "wheelchair": false,
      "start_date": 2020
    }
  }
  ..
```

We use CoreData in swift to store json data and retreive them. We want to save our json data in our database, therefore we use the Example.json in Service.swift as jsonData. I provided the POI model as it was created by XCode and it uses Codeable with decode and encode. The context is passed with Dependecy Injection and it is a singleton. The model uses Transformable with “NSSecureUnarchiveFromData” as Transformer. The problem is: while decoding I can see all properties in debug mode, but when the context should be saved, all values are “nil”. How to fix this? The other models are similar so I haven’t included them. If you need any other files or parts of them feel free to ask.

Comment: Sounds like a concurrency issue - are you downloading and processing that json on a background thread?

Comment: That json is downloaded before, if I add breakpoints in the lines where the properties are added I can read the contents properly. That's why I cannot figure out how self.<property> is set but seems to be nil in the context.

Comment: Which property or properties use transformable attributes?

Comment: @TomHarrington Every property which isn't a basic type, so "title", "properties", "coordinates". I use the classes you can see in the model as custom class, for example coordinates is a Geometry class, which is a model itself. Title is a dictionary, properties too but it uses any because there could be another dict included, but we managed to get everything to work before we implemented CoreData, now it has to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear from the question, but it sounds similar to a common problem when using values that don't work with transformable attributes. A transformable must be something that conforms to `NSCoding` or `NSSecureCoding`. Swift types often don't do this, because you can't conform to those protocols unless you inherit from `NSObject`. Using `Codable` is not the same thing. It serves the same purpose but it isn't interoperable with `NSCoding`.

When this happens, decoding the JSON works, but the decoded data doesn't get saved because it can't be transformed.

If this seems like the case here, you can change the attributes to "binary", and then do your own conversion to/from `Data` when accessing them. Or, try to change to a type that conforms to `NSCoding` and stick with transformables.